# Extending "final" interfaces/closed codebase interfaces

Tags: java, generics, java-8

Let's say I wanted extend something **like** the `Stream` Java 8 interface (I am using this interface as an example only to illustrate a point). To simplify my example lets say the interface only had two methods and is final:

```
public final interface Stream<T> {

    Stream<T> limit(long maxSize);
    <R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R> mapper);
}
```

Now for all my different projects I may want to write different extension methods specific to the project, but what I don't want to have to do is implement the whole `Stream` interface in my extensions class.

So I am thinking, write an abstract extensions class that I can just extend when I want to write a new set of extensions. So I have got this far with the implementation:

```
public abstract class AbstractStreamExtensions<A extends Stream<T>, T> implements Stream<T> {

    private final Stream<T> stream;
    private final Constructor<?> constructor;

    public AbstractStreamExtensions(Stream<T> stream) {
        this.stream = stream;

        try {
            constructor = this.getClass().getDeclaredConstructor(Stream.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public A limit(long maxSize) {
        try {
            return (A) constructor.newInstance(stream.limit(maxSize));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

With the concrete class looking something like this:

```
public class StreamExtensions<T> extends AbstractStreamExtensions<StreamExtensions<T>, T> {

    private final Stream<T> stream;

    public StreamExtensions(Stream<T> stream) {
        super(stream);
        this.stream = stream;
    }

    public StreamExtensions<T> limit5() {
        return new StreamExtensions<>(stream.limit(5));
    }
}
```

Which would be used like this:

```
Stream<String> stream = // ...
StreamExtensions<String> = new StreamExtensions(stream).map(...).limit5()
```

I hope you can see what I am trying to achieve here. I still get the same `Stream` auto-complete API in my idea, only without having to implement the already existing interface again.

The above code won't compile, this is because there is no implementation for the `map()` function on the interface. Now I can implement this easy enough in the concrete `StreamExtensions` class if I wanted to but I'd prefer to have it in the `AbstractStreamExtensions` as it will just be calling the `Stream` method like `limit()` does.

Is there a way I can have the implementation for `map()` in the `AbstractStreamExtensions` base class that will compile and give me types when using the auto-complete and documentation features of eclipse and intellij?

Comment: This is pretty standard for a *Decorator*. It might help us understand what you're trying to accomplish with a more concrete example.

Comment: @TomG - I've made an edit, maybe it will make more sense now.

Comment: OK, I see the use case now. Can you elaborate on why you have two types, R and T? That part I'm still not quite following. In fact you don't use either type argument at all in the example.

Comment: @TomG - I've changed the example again, I am hoping this change will make alot more sense.

Comment: Are you trying to reuse the Stream? I think Streams are designed to be one time objects.

Comment: There is no sense it adding a `final` modifier to an `interface`. Besides that, you don’t need a reflective `Constructor` if you let each subclass pass its own constructor reference (`StreamExtensions::new`) as `Function<Stream<T>,A>` to the superclass constructor. Analyzing the actual problem, there are 10 intermediate operations which the base class can implement returning `A` and 6 intermediate ops which don’t return a `Stream` and 19 terminal operations, plus `isParallel`/`onClose`/`close`, read, 38 methods implementable by the base class and two remaining operations (`map` and `flatMap`)…